# Cython For Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cython

Is it possible to use Cython in appengine (with Python 2.7 specifically)? I could see using it when some code is not performing well, and could use a speed boost by having a statically defined type, or loop optimization, etc...

Comment: In a round about way it will be possible for App Engine VM based backends to run cything at some point soon - Trusted tester signup was announced a little while ago https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/gRZNqlQPKys/BbOHxcgYt2IJ , however this isn't really what you asked and you should spend time reading the basic docs on appengine.

Comment: @Tim you're right in that it's not exactly what I asked for, but very interesting nonetheless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is very clearly not possible. GAE has very strong restrictions on what you can run inside its sandbox, and one of the most definitively spelled-out restrictions is that you [cannot run arbitrary C code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox):

> All code for the Python runtime environment must be pure Python, and not include any C extensions or other code that must be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with Managed VMs.

The following project will serve as an example:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-vm-fortunespeak-python

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are dated, but the question is still a good one. You can run Cython with gcloud now provided that you cythonize at build time.

For example:

```
# Load python version
FROM python:3.11

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies and cythonize .pyx files
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup.py build_ext --inplace

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn 
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 run:app
```

Now, there is an interesting twist if you use a SLIM build of python. In that case gcc is not included and so cythonizing will fail. So then you have to load gcc by hand:

```
# The slim python doesnt include gcc
FROM python:3.11-slim 

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install gcc and cythonize 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install gcc 
RUN python setup_pyd.py build_ext --inplace

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn 
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 run:app
```